# Breaking apart xml tags with the lxml module

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm trying to break apart the tags (on one line) so that I can print the different tags and the content on different lines while ignoring `<br>`.

Snippet of a few lines of content I'm trying to break apart.

```xml
<stats>+40 Ability Power<br>+25 Magic Resist<br>+20% Cooldown Reduction<br><mana>+75% Base Mana Regen </mana></stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive:</unique> Gain 20% of the <a href='premitigation'><font color='#6666FF'><u>premitigation</u></font></a> damage dealt to champions as Blood Charges, up to <levelScale>100 - 250</levelScale>  max. Healing or shielding another ally consumes charges to heal them, up to the original effect amount.<br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Harmony:</unique> Grants bonus % Base Health Regen equal to your bonus % Base Mana Regen.<br><br><rules>(Maximum amount of Blood Charges stored is based on level. Healing amplification is applied to the total heal value.)</rules>
<stats>+10% Critical Strike Chance</stats>
<stats>+45 Attack Damage<br>+10% Life Steal</stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive:</unique> Basic attacks grant +6 Attack Damage and +1% Life Steal for 8 seconds on hit (effect stacks up to 5 times).
<stats>+300 Health<br>+50 Attack Damage<br>+20% Cooldown Reduction</stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive:</unique> Dealing physical damage to an enemy champion Cleaves them, reducing their Armor by 5% for 6 seconds (stacks up to 6 times, up to 30%).<br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Rage:</unique> Dealing physical damage grants 20 movement speed for 2 seconds. Assists on Cleaved enemy champions or kills on any unit grant 60 movement speed for 2 seconds instead. This Movement Speed is halved for ranged champions.
```

But when I try parsing the xml-like string from the `lxml` module.

```py
root = etree.Element(string)
```

It give me the error:

```
ValueError: Invalid tag name "<stats>+40 Attack Damage<br>+80 Ability Power</stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive:</unique> Heal for 15% of damage dealt. This is 33% as effective for Area of Effect damage.<br><active>UNIQUE Active - Lightning Bolt:</active> Deals 250 (+30% of Ability Power) magic damage and slows the target champion's Movement Speed by 40% for 2 seconds (40 second cooldown, shared with other <font color='#9999FF'><a href='itembolt'>Hextech</a></font> items)."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you show is not XML. An XML parser will not be able to read this.

Use an HTML parser, they accept a wider range of input. See http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html.

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

test_string = "<stats>+40 Ability Power<br>+25 Magic Resist<br>+20% Cooldown Reduction<br><mana>+75% Base Mana Regen </mana></stats><br><br><unique>UNIQUE Passive:</unique> Gain 20% of the <a href='premitigation'><font color='#6666FF'><u>premitigation</u></font></a> damage dealt to champions as Blood Charges, up to <levelScale>100 - 250</levelScale>  max. Healing or shielding another ally consumes charges to heal them, up to the original effect amount.<br><unique>UNIQUE Passive - Harmony:</unique> Grants bonus % Base Health Regen equal to your bonus % Base Mana Regen.<br><br><rules>(Maximum amount of Blood Charges stored is based on level. Healing amplification is applied to the total heal value.)</rules>"
html_file = StringIO(test_string)

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
doc = etree.parse(html_file, parser)

print(doc)
# prints: <lxml.etree._ElementTree object at 0x03036A58>
```

After that you can search and modify the document tree with all the methods lxml offers.

Note: `StringIO` is only necessary for the sake of the example above, to make it possible that a string can be used like a file. If you already have a file you don't need `StringIO`. Just use the file directly.

If you are actually looking for a web scraping solution, look at a library that does that. [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) and [pyQuery](https://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/) come to mind, they will do all the parsing for you and offer a nicer interface to access the data on the page.